# Problem with CrunchBase API and jQuery $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I am trying to simply send an alert with a "name", but It doesn't seem to work. Advice?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/companies/permalink?name=Google", function(data) {
   alert("Hello: " + data.name);
  });
 });
```

Here is what the JSON contains:

```
{"crunchbase_url": "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/google",
 "permalink": "google",
 "name": "Google"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Normally* you'd use JSONP here by adding `&callback=?` to your URL, *however* a JSONP callback is not supported in this case, from the [crunchbase API documentation](http://groups.google.com/group/crunchbase-api/web/api-v1-documentation):

> **List Entities**
>
> To retrieve a list of all of the entities in a certain namespace on CrunchBase, use a URL of the form:
>
> `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/<plural-namespace>`
>
> The plural available namespaces are:
>
> - companies
> - people
> - financial-organizations
> - products
> - service-providers
>
> **This action does not support JavaScript callbacks.**

The bottom line is the most important, you'll see that this: http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/companies/permalink?name=Google&callback=callme still results in regular JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: Thankfully, the OP apparently only really wants to load a single company, so moving him to the singular actions may resolve that bit.

Comment: what is the difference between &callback=? and ?callback=?

Comment: @Matchu - that requires a different input though, for example `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/companies/permalink?name=A+Small+Orange` vs `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/a-small-orange.js` (and others where the translation isn't so straightforward, like a `&` being encoded...so it's not the same method :)

Comment: @ddrmaxgt37 - Just the querystring format, the first parameter should be `?param=blah`, others after it should be `&param=blah`

Comment: Mhm. It's a different URL that it seems he really wants.

Comment: @Matchu - are you jut ignoring my previous comment, that it searches in a completely different way, *not* based on name?

Comment: Hm. I don't know enough about this site to know what the difference is between `?name=A+Small+Orange` and `a-small-orange.js`, since they both look like they're finding by name to me. Ah, well. I defer to your judgment :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not Crunchbase, you can't send that request. For security reasons, only `www.crunchbase.com` may send AJAX requests to `www.crunchbase.com`. (Imagine we were talking about `www.bankofamerica.com` and I were logged in. It'd be a problem if just any site could send arbitrary requests to `www.bankofamerica.com` with my cookies attached.)

The [API documentation](http://groups.google.com/group/crunchbase-api/web/api-v1-documentation) does indicate a JSON-P option, however. If you're interested, you can look up the implementation details, but the important bit is that the JSON-P technique is able to circumvent the domain name restriction because Crunchbase's API will allow you to.

The URL `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/google.js` is a similar resource to the one you mentioned, but this particular URL allows you to use JSON-P, whereas the one you posted does not. jQuery allows you to do this easily: pass the URL to `$.getJSON` as `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/google.js?callback=?` (the bit about the callback is important!), and jQuery will fill in the blanks and handle the magic script loading behind the scenes. It's very fancy :)